# What is the function of "for more productivity" on this sentence?

Tags: complements, adverbials, functions

> rapid population increases drive the search for more productivity.

What is the function of "for more productivity"? is it a complement or an adverbial?

Thank you!

Comment: *More productivity* is the goal of the *search*. I think the unit of thought should either be "the search for more productivity" or "more productivity", but not "for more productivity".

Comment: So, is it a complement?

Comment: It’s just natural. @hixann

Comment: It's like "the search for hidden treasure". It's simply the object of the preposition.

Answer (score 0):

If we rephrase it to say,

> A rapid population increase drives the search for more productivity

it becomes self evident: A rapid increase in population [an increase of people] creates a push for more productivity, or, gives people the drive, or motivation, to find ways to become more productive [in tandem with population growth].

Productivity might refer to producing more food, more housing, more living needs, etc.